# If is possible to set badge number from "today" widget

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, badge

If is possible to set badge number from "today" widget?

I understand it is not possible to set directly in the widget, but is it possible to communicate with the app and set it there, without open the app to front? I have tried NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName, but I cannot get it to work across widget and app.

I understand background fetch may work, but it is quite inefficient to have a routine background fetch just to the badge number on icon.

Any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and I don't think that this is currently possible (unfortunately). So I filed an enhancement request via https://bugreport.apple.com/. You may do the same.